# Setting attribute of one model in the create view of another model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, nested-attributes

I have a user model that has_one profile, and the profile belongs to the user. The profile has a `type` column for single table inheritance that is either "artist" or "listener". I want the user to set this upon signing up in the new User view. I therefore have this code in the form:

```
<%= f.fields_for :profile do |t| %>
 <div class ="field">
    <%= t.label :type, "Are you an artist or listener?" %><br />
    <%= t.radio_button :type "artist" %>
    <%= t.radio_button :type "listener" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

and this in my user model:

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :profile
```

But I get his error:

```
ArgumentError in Videos#index

Showing /rubyprograms/dreamstill/app/views/videos/_video.html.erb where line #3 raised:

No association found for name `profile'. Has it been defined yet?
```

Why is this, and how can I fix it?

Also I am very confused why the error brings up line 3 in my video partial, which does not mention `profile` at all...

UPDATE:

Here's the entire form:

```
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
  <% if @user.errors.any? %>
  <div id="errorExplanation">
    <h2><%= pluralize(@user.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this user from being saved:</h2>
    <ul>
    <% @user.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
      <li><%= msg %></li>
    <% end %>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :email %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :email %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password_confirmation, "Password Confirmation" %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %>
  </div>
  <%= f.fields_for :profile do |t| %>
    <div class ="field">
      <%= t.label :type, "Are you an artist or listener?" %><br />
      <%= t.radio_button :type "artist" %>
      <%= t.radio_button :type "listener" %>
    </div>
  <% end %>     
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name, "Full Name" %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>
  <div class="action">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

And these are the three lines relevant to profiles in the user model:

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :profile
before_create :build_profile 
has_one :profile
```

Comment: Show 1. User model, 2. entire form

Comment: you should declare `has_one :profile` first

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you should edit your model and set all this stuff in right order:

```
has_one :profile  # it should be first
accepts_nested_attributes_for :profile
before_create :build_profile
```

Comment: by the way... the radio buttons for your previous answer are not appearing in the form for some reason... the html for them isn't there

Comment: you forgot comma `<%= t.radio_button :type, "artist" %>` between `:type` and `artist`

Comment: yea, i actually put that in, and the buttons still don't appear... it's strange

Comment: it is because profile is not exist. try this `<%= f.fields_for :profile, Profile.new do |t| %>`

Comment: thanks!, by the way `type` wasn't set for the profile when I created a new user, should I create a `create` method for that in the profile controller? :/